# simplify the definition of the layers in the VAE

Tags: python, autoencoder, encoder

To simplify the definition of the layers in the VAE and the usage of the nonlinearities I have to use torch.nn.Sequential in the below code. How can I change this definition for nonlinearities?

```
class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VAE, self).__init__()
        self.fc0 = nn.Linear(2, K)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(K, K)
        self.fc21 = nn.Linear(K, K)
        self.fc22 = nn.Linear(K, K)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(K, K)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(K, K)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(K, 2)
    def encode(self, x):
        h1 = F.selu(self.fc1(F.selu(self.fc0(x))))
        return self.fc21(h1), self.fc22(h1)
'''
```